# Google App Engine: local testing a simple hello world

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to make a simple Hello World working in local via the Google App Engine plugin for Eclipse Helios.
The problem comes when want to launch the serveur with the eclipse tool (right-clic on my project -> Run As -> Web Application), the console always display these logs:

```
2012-04-17 19:01:09.126 java[4019:407] [Java CocoaComponent compatibility mode]: Enabled
2012-04-17 19:01:09.127 java[4019:407] [Java CocoaComponent compatibility mode]: Setting timeout for SWT to 0.100000
Usage: <dev-appserver> [options] <war directory>

Options:
 --help, -h                 Show this help message and exit.
 --server=SERVER            The server to use to determine the latest
  -s SERVER                   SDK version.
 --address=ADDRESS          The address of the interface on the local machine
  -a ADDRESS                  to bind to (or 0.0.0.0 for all interfaces).
 --port=PORT                The port number to bind to on the local machine.
  -p PORT
 --sdk_root=root            Overrides where the SDK is located.
 --disable_update_check     Disable the check for newer SDK versions.
 --generated_dir=dir        Set the directory where generated files are created.
```

The local server works when I use command bellow:

```
./appengine-java-sdk/bin/dev_appserver.sh appengine-java-sdk/demos/guestbook/war
```

Does anyone has some idee for making it working ?

Thanks by advice and sorry for my bad English...

Comment: Have you configured the Google SDK appropriately in Eclipse? GO to Window--> Preferences--> Google, and check if the GAE and GWT sdk are pointing to directories where the SDK residses

Comment: Yes, I just solve the problem :)
It was the conf file appengine-web.xml which was not correctly filled. Thanks Google for light error message...

Comment: @pfevrier can you please be more specific what was missing?

Comment: Sorry @TWiStErRob, I don't remember what was missing exactly (this topic is more than 1 year old:). Good luck !!!

Answer (score 8):

i also got into the same problem. But my solution was deleting the existing launch configuration (in Run > Run configurations), close the dialog, and then try right-clicking on your project > Run As > Web Application.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the space in the Project Name, which coincides with the folder name in the workspace. Whoever is calling the dev server launcher didn't use quotes around the war directory.